# OpenGL ES: Translate a matrix to a particular point

Tags: iphone, graphics, opengl-es, matrix

Hi guys I am working on a app which requires the use of opengl es. However I have some questions. My task at hand is to rotate a matrix about an arbitrary point say (0,0,0). I did some research on google and the most common approach is

1. translate the matrix to (0,0,0)
2. Rotate the matrix
3. Translate the matrix back to its original position

Effectively

```
glTranslatef(centerX, centerY, centerZ);
glRotatef(angle, 0, 0, 1);
glTranslatef(-centerX, -centerY, -centerZ);
```

However my problem is I am using opengl es 2.0. The function translatef does not exist in opengl es 2.0. I have a function called as translateBy but I am unable to figure out how to use translateBy function to translate my matrix to a certain point

Thanks any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In OpenGL ES 2.0 you have to use vertex shader and just update the modelview matrix in every frame using

```
GLint modelviewmatrix = glGetUniformLocation(m_simpleProgram, "ModelviewMatrix");
matrx4 modelviewMatrix = rotation * translation;
glUniformMatrix4fv(modelviewmatrix, 1, 0, modelviewMatrix.Pointer());
```

assuming matrx4 as a matrix class of 4x4. and rotation and translation are the 4x4 matrix objects for rotation and translation.
Just make your own translate and rotate functions,
Translatef(x,y,z) is equivalent to

```
  Matrx4 Translate( x,  y,  z)
{
    Matrx4 m;
    m = { 1, 0, 0, 0,
          0, 1, 0, 0,
          0, 0, 1, 0,
          x, y, z, 1 }
    return m;
}
```

and Rotatef(degree, vector3 axis) is equivalent to

```
 Matrx4 Rotate( float degree, vector3 axis)
{
    float radians = degrees * 3.14159f / 180.0f;
    float s = std::sin(radians);
    float c = std::cos(radians);

    Matrx4 m = Identity(); /// load identity matrix
    m[0] = c + (1 - c) * axis.x * axis.x;
    m[1] = (1 - c) * axis.x * axis.y - axis.z * s;
    m[2] = (1 - c) * axis.x * axis.z + axis.y * s;
    m[4] = (1 - c) * axis.x * axis.y + axis.z * s;
    m[5] = c + (1 - c) * axis.y * axis.y;
    m[6] = (1 - c) * axis.y * axis.z - axis.x * s;
    m[8] = (1 - c) * axis.x * axis.z - axis.y * s;
    m[9] = (1 - c) * axis.y * axis.z + axis.x * s;
    m[10] = c + (1 - c) * axis.z * axis.z;
    return m;
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer .... Just to make sure we are both on the same page. The function Translate( x,  y, z) will translate a matrix to the point x,y,z as opposed to moving it by (x,y,z)? Now my next question is I want to rotate all the matrices about the center of the screen. I can get the x,y cordinates of the screen center by using self.bounds.width and self.bounds.height. Can these cordinates be plugged in directly into the matrix? Or in other words are these cordinates in the same cordinate system as the matrices?

Comment: and for the second one, how can be the screen coordinates be the same as the world coordinates. you have to convert them to rotate all the matrix about the center of the screen.

Comment: I am sorry I am completely at loss on this one? How would one convert the screen cordinates to the world cordinates

Comment: Unfortunately the translate function did not work. I used the function as is but did not get the desired results. I ended up doing match magic in the translateBy function to get the desired result.